# Change the colors of JvectorMap when there are 2 maps on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jvectormap

i am using Jvectormap to place 2 maps on my page.
the maps are placed normally and everything is fine. they are placed in 2 different divs:

```
<div id="map1">
    </div>

<div id="map2">
    </div>
```

and the Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#map1').vectorMap({
        color: '#aaaaaa',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        hoverOpacity: 1,
        hoverColor: true
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#map2').vectorMap({
        color: '#aaaaaa',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        hoverOpacity: 1,
    });
});
```

Now when I try to change the colors of map2 dynamically using:

```
$("#map2").vectorMap("set", "colors", colorsDictionnary);
```

The colors of the first one only is changed.

and this happens only when changing colors. Always the first one have it's colors changed even if I am using `$("#map2")`

How can change the colors of the map2 without touching map1?

Thank you very much for any help, I really need it

Comment: there is no need to use 2 `$(function () {
`

Comment: yes I putted them in 1 function. but that doesn't affect the problem. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does this accomplish what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/qFHyF/

This answer builds upon an answer I posted to a question here: 
[jvectormap region colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867615/jvectormap-region-colors/12868989#12868989)

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
    var myCustomColorsOne = {
        'AU-SA': '#4E7387',
        'AU-WA': '#333333',
        'AU-VIC': '#89AFBF',
        'AU-TAS': '#817F8E',
        'AU-QLD': '#344B5E',
        'AU-NSW': '#344B5E',
        'AU-ACT': '#344B5E',
        'AU-NT': '#344B5E'
    };
    var myCustomColorsTwo = {
        'AU-SA': '#803300',
        'AU-WA': '#993D00',
        'AU-VIC': '#B24700',
        'AU-TAS': '#CC5200',
        'AU-QLD': '#E65C00',
        'AU-NSW': '#FF7519',
        'AU-ACT': '#FF8533',
        'AU-NT': '#FFB280'
    };
    var myCustomColorsThree = {
        'AU-SA': '#B8E186',
        'AU-WA': '#B8E186',
        'AU-VIC': '#B8E186',
        'AU-TAS': '#B8E186',
        'AU-QLD': '#B8E186',
        'AU-NSW': '#B8E186',
        'AU-ACT': '#B8E186',
        'AU-NT': '#B8E186'
    };

    mapOne = new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'au_merc_en',
        container: $('#ausieOne'),
        backgroundColor: '#EFF7FF',
        series: {
            regions: [{
                attribute: 'fill'}]
        }
    });

    mapTwo = new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'au_merc_en',
        container: $('#ausieTwo'),
        backgroundColor: '#EFF7FF',
        colors: '#3377CC',
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#B8E186'
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                attribute: 'fill'}]
        }
    });

    mapOne.series.regions[0].setValues(myCustomColorsOne);

    $("#color-changer").click(function() {
        var $that = $(this);
        if ($that.hasClass("green")) {
            $that.removeClass("green");
            mapTwo.series.regions[0].setValues(myCustomColorsTwo);
        } else {
            $that.addClass("green");
            mapTwo.series.regions[0].setValues(myCustomColorsThree);
        }
        return false;
    });

})();​
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="color-changer" class="green">Change colors of Map Two</a>
<p>Map One</p>
<div style="width: 354px; height: 300px" id="ausieOne" data-projection="mill" data-name="au_mill_en"></div>
<p>Map Two</p>
<div style="width: 354px; height: 300px" id="ausieTwo" data-projection="mill" data-name="au_mill_en"></div>
```